# Need Regular Expression to match name/value pairs in different formats

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm pulling in ASP/VBScript configuration files via PHP Curl to do some file processing and want to return some values.

The strings look like this:

```
config1 = ""  
config2 = "VALUE:1:0:9" 'strange value comment 
otherconfig = False 
yetanotherconfig = False 'some comment
```

Basically, its name value pairs separated by equal signs, with a value optionally enclosed  within **quotation marks** followed optionally by a comment.

I want to return the actual VALUE (False, VALUE:1:0:9, etc..) in ONE matching group regardless of the format the string is in.

Here's the pattern i'm passing to preg_match so far:

```
$pattern = '/\s*'.$configname.'\s*\=\s*(\".*?\"|.*?\r)/'
```

$configname is the name of the specific configuration i'm looking for, so I pass it in with a variable.

I'm still getting parentheses included back with the value (instead of the value itself) and i'm getting comments returned with the value as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any parentheses in your config sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning matching value in ONE matching group if difficult because of the double quotes alternative. Back references can help:

```
$pattern = '/\s*'.$configname.'\s*=\s*("?)(?<value>.*?)\1\s*[\'$]/'
```

should do the trick. Then use `$result['value']`.

Explained in english it does:

- I skip the spaces identifier spaces = spaces (easy)
- may match a `"` referenced as \1 (the first capture parenthesis)
- match any char not greedily referenced as `value`
- match \1 (so `"` if there was one before, or nothing if not)
- may match some spaces
- must match a starting comment `'` or an end of line

Without back references:

```
$pattern = '/\s*'.$configname.'\s*=\s*(?:"(.*?)"|(.*?)\s*[\'$])/'
```

More efficient but value is in `$result[1]` or `$result[2]`.

Understand your mistakes:

- You need `\` only to protect the string quote itself (here simple quote) or to avoid a preg reserved char to be interpreted (as `.`, `^`, `$` ...)
- End of line is marked as `$`, not \r or \n
- You never avoided the commentary

Comment: forgot some `preg_quotes()` ? :-)

Comment: On `$configname` to improve robustness?

Answer (score 0):

\r is going to match a CR character (carriage return).
You're essentially saying I want to match "???????" or ????????[carriage return]

Of course you'll get the apostrophe, you've matched it.
You'll have to strip these things off.

patter = '/\s*'.$configname.'\s*\=\s*(\")(.*?)(?(1)\"|)\s*/'

Answer (score 0):

This one will work:

```
$pattern = '/
    \s*
    # name
    (?P<name>.*?)
    # =
    \s*=\s*
    # value
    (?P<val>
        "(?P<quoted>([^"]|\\\\"|\\\\\\\\)*)"
        |(?P<raw>.*?)
    )
    # comment
    \s*(?P<comment>\'.*)?
$/xm';
```

This will match every key=value pair in the input string, instead of just a specific one.

The regex takes care for quotes and escaped quotes (`\"`) in quoted values (e.g. `"foo\"bar"`).

Use it with a function like this:

```
function parse_config($string) {
    $pattern = '/
        \s*
        # name
        (?P<name>.*?)
        # =
        \s*=\s*
        # value
        (?P<val>
            "(?P<quoted>([^"]|\\\\"|\\\\\\\\)*)"
            |(?P<raw>.*?)
        )
        # comment
        \s*(?P<comment>\'.*)?
    $/xm';

    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $config = array();
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $name = $match['name'];
        if (!empty($match['quoted'])) {
            $value = str_replace(array('\\"','\\\\'), array('"','\\'), $match['quoted']);
        } else if (isset($match['raw'])) {
            $value = $match['raw'];
        } else {
            $value = '';
        }
        $config[$name] = $value;
    }

    return $config;
}
```

Example:

```
$string = "a = b\n
c=\"d\\\"e\\\\fgh\" ' comment";

$config = parse_config($string);

// output:

array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd"e\fgh');
```

Other example:

```
$string = <<<EOF
config1 = ""
config2 = "VALUE:1:0:9" 'strange value comment
otherconfig = False
yetanotherconfig = False 'some comment
EOF;

print_r(parse_config($string));

// output:

Array
(
    [config1] => 
    [config2] => VALUE:1:0:9
    [otherconfig] => False
    [yetanotherconfig] => False
)
```